# Unexpected Non Void return value in CollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath Datasource method

Tags: swift, parse-platform

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PictureCellForHomeVC {
        picArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                if let data = data {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    cell.imageView.image = image
                    return cell
                }
            }
        })
    }else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

In the above code I receive the error:

`Unexpected Non Void return value in void function`

The `picArray` in my above code is code with `PFFile` objects which I can call the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` method.

I understand what the error means since the completionHandler of the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` returns `void` so I can't return my cell in it, but I am stuck on how to fix this problem.

I can't even pass a seperate closure to the method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` since I do not call the method and it is a datasource method. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Do the return `cell` after the block code (which should be async), after the `})` and before the `}else`. Even if you don't find the image, you have to return the cell.

Comment: @Larme Of so if I put `return cell` before the `}else` then even if the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` returns the callback to the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` will still run and update the image correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to return something that you think is returning within your function but is actually trying to return something from `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` which is supposed to return `void` (which is not allowed hence the error).

You could do something like this which loads the image in the background while giving it a placeholder image in the meantime (for added effect):

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? PictureCellForHomeVC {
        picArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                self.loadImage(inImageView: cell.imageView, withData: data)
            }
        })
        return cell 
} else {
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}


func loadImage(inImageView imageView: PFImageView, withData imageFile: PFFile?) {
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png") // Some placeholder while the image loads asyncronously
    if let imageFile = imageFile {
        imageView.file = imageFile
        imageView.loadInBackground(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok that's a good idea as well. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: In case of `if let cell`, `cell` is not returned in your code.

Comment: I see that you edited your answer, but you still don't return the dequeued cell.

Comment: There I returned it

Comment: @Aaron Also shouldn't you put this line: `imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")` in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. Like before the `return cell` statement put `cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")`. So it will show a placeholder image while it is downloading asynchronously. Then when it is downloaded it will call the `loadImage` method in the callback of `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`.

Comment: That's entirely up to you. The location of a placeholder image isn't relevant to the answer so you could place it wherever you see fit.